# Как отправить запрос на сервер в php

Tags: php

Задание такое, c помощью php нужно отправить запрос на whois.ru и узнать, свободен или занят домен. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: где застопорились?

Comment: php на самом начале изучения, и пока я даже не понимаю как это работает. Хотелось бы разобраться самому, но даже не понимаю, что гуглить. Есть у вас какая нибудь статья или книга по этому вопросу?

Comment: file_get_contents https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php может прочитать содержимое по url. Если надо сложнее curl https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php разобрать html - domDocument  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Спасибо! Постараюсь разобраться

Comment: если будут конкретный вопросы, вы можете спросить и тут